# How to configure Cloudflare DNS for path based routes with a target like how you define for a CNAME record?

Tags: cloudflare, dns-hosting

I have a site, lets call it mydomain.com. The site has some subdomains (subdomain.mydomain.com) and some path based routing (mydomain.com/path1). The thing is that when a user clicks on links to either those subdomain or path based routes the website should open up a new app, but still appear with the same root domain (mydomain.com)

For subdomain, I got that down no problem. Just create a CNAME record with the Name field = subdomain_name and the Target = myTarget (which in this case is a AWS CloudFront distribution). This works perfect. A user selects a link and the site navigates to the subdomain, which is actually a brand new SPA served up by AWS CloudFront+S3.

What I can't figure out is what record to create for the apps that get deployed by the path-based routes. For example a user selects a link and the front-end navigates to mydomain.com/somePath and when it does I need Cloudflare to target another CloudFront+S3 distribution that has it's own SPA deployed there.

If anyone can explain how to handle path based-routing in Cloudflare with targets like CloudFront it would be much appreciated, because I am stumped on this!